# MongoDB get element in the middle of a find sort result using nodejs native driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, performance

I'm having this large collection and i need to sort it by a field `bo` and get the document that is in the middle of the result without looping through all results.
So for this example:

```
[
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd990, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '1', bo: 100 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd991, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '2', bo: 200 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd992, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '3', bo: 300 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd993, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '4', bo: 400 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd994, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '5', bo: 500 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd995, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '7', bo: 660 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd996, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '6', bo: 670 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd997, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '8', bo: 680 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd998, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '9', bo: 550 },
 {_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd999, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '0', bo: 700 }
]
```

i need to get only the document

```
{_id: 5d36b8f79600563a2cecd998, file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb', cant: '9', bo: 550 }
```

so the middle or the first after middle ...

I've tried getting all the results in an array, and finding it's middle
`var half_length = Math.ceil(myArray.length / 2);`
then getting that element, but this operation is too slow...

```js
 db
  .collection('history')
  .find({ file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb' })
  .sort({ bo: 1 })
  .toArray(function(err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
   var half_length = Math.ceil(result.length / 2);
   console.log(result[half_length]);
  });
};
```

I need to find just the one record that is in the middle of the result of a find/sort query without saving it to an array. (If it's possible)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find the count of the documents with the required filters

```
const count = db.collection('history').countDocuments({file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb'});
const skipCount = Math.ceil(count/2) - 1;
```

For getting the Middle of the result

```
db.collection('history').find({file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb'}).sort({ bo: 1 }).skip(skipCount).limit(1);
```

Using the node-mongodb-native API you can write the query as

```
   db.collection('history').countDocuments({ file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb' }, function(err, count) {
        const skipCount = Math.ceil(count/2) - 1;
        db.collection('history').find({ file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb' }).sort({ bo: 1 }).skip(skipCount).limit(1) .toArray(function(err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // Here is your result
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I'm getting a DeprecationWarning: collection.count is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version.

Comment: count returns a promise, and skipCount returns NaN, i think we must use a callback: db.collection('history').countDocuments({ file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb' }, function(err, count) {const skipCount = Math.ceil(count/2) - 1;  })

Comment: I've solved it by using a callback on initial count and getting the middle of the result inside that callback, you can edit your answer and i'll mark it as accepted: db.collection('history').countDocuments({ file_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb' }, function(err, count) { const skipCount = Math.ceil(count/2) - 1; db
   .collection('history')
   .find({ prods_manopere_id: '5d2393b912c90b2b9c51d0eb' })
   .sort({ bo: 1 })
   .skip(skipCount)
   .limit(1)
   .toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
   }); }) Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196860/discussion-between-chyangba-and-gabriel).